# Change workbook reference in all cells of a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if there is a workaround using a VBA subroutine to change reference in all cells of a worksheet.

The scenario:

I copied this worksheet 'Strut' from another workbook that also contains identical worksheet 'section'

All the reference of the copied sheets are still pointing to the original workbook, where I would like to change it to refer to the worksheet 'section' within the new workbook itself. Kindly advice if it's possible to change all affected cells with a subroutine. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl-H to open the Find and Replace window. Change the search scope to Workbook and replace "[LACED STRUT.xlsx]" with "". "Replace All"

Comment: To add to @OliverLeung suggestion, I turn off automatic calculation, do the replace then turn it back on - I find it is quicker...

Comment: Also, suggest to check your Formula->Named Manager, Conditional Formatting and Data Validation, which can induce external reference during copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Change References in Worksheet

- Insert a new standard module into your workbook (e.g. `Module1`).
- Copy the following code into the module.
- Adjust the three **const**ants if necessary.
- Save the workbook.
- If the referred workbook is closed, you will have to add the complete path.
- Finally run the `Sub`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub changeReferences()

    Const wsName As String = "Strut"
    Const strOLD As String = "'[LACED STRUT.xlsx]section'"
    Const strNEW As String = "section"

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).UsedRange.Cells
        cel.Formula = Replace(cel.Formula, strOLD, strNEW)
    Next cel

End Sub
```